# Integrate over the unit circle using parametrization

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I've been told to integrate the below using the parametrization $z(t) = \exp{(i \cdot t)}$. I can write my integral out and I tried using integration by parts to solve it but I got nowhere.

$C$ is the unit circle $(|z| = 1)$

$$\int_{C}\ z^2 \cot{z} ~dz$$

This is what I've done:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ e^{2it}cot(e^{it})ie^{it}dt$$ = $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ ie^{3it}cot(e^{it})dt $$

From here i Tired to set u = $cot(e^{it})$ and dv = $e^{i3t}$ but I couldn't get anywhere with this

Comment: Suggest you show your steps or folks won't know how to help.

Comment: I suspect that you meant that $C$ is the unit circle $|z| = 1$. $ |z| < 1$ is the (open) unit disk.

Comment: I did mean that - just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The integrand is analytic in the region.

Comment: But doesn't cot(z) have a problem at z = 0 because of the sin(z)?

Comment: Yes but multiplying by $z^2$ clears it out.  It's a first order pole.

Comment: I don't think I've learnt about orders of poles yet

Comment: It's a simple pole.  If you look at the Taylor series of the $\sin z$ in the denominator, you can factor out a $z$.  Then cancel it.  Your left with $z/(1+\mathcal o(z^2))$.  That denominator  equals $1$ at $z=0$.  As a result, the function is defined and analytic at $0$.

Comment: In a neighborhood of zero, that is.  It'll take a while to get used to some of this stuff.  I think I should have written "big oh", not "little oh".  You'll also learn about them at some point.

Comment: Okay thanks for this. Maybe this will make more sense after next weeks classes!

Comment: You bet.  And good luck!